# Laptop having random and frequent slowdowns

Tags: windows-7, performance

So I have a Toshiba satellite with an i7 processor. It's under a year old and has been working fine until about a month ago. My problem is that no matter what I do with my laptop, whether gaming, browsing, even booting it up, there will be frequent slowdowns to the point where I can't even do anything.

These slowdowns last for roughly 10-15 seconds, but with a devilish frequency that makes using my laptop less than enjoyable at times. I've checked for viruses and malware and removed whatever I could find. Problem persists.

Not sure if it might be a heating problem perhaps. I'd like to know whether there is something I can do, and what exactly is causing my laptop to be like this. Is it permanent damage?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: look if you have overheating issues. Maybe the CPU throttles to avoid damage.

Comment: What does the event log show from a previous time when there was a slowdown?  That is probably the first place to look for errors.

Comment: Make sure the CPU fan is spinning. You can usually tell be ear. You can use compressed air to remove dust from the heat sinks.

Answer (score 2):

--> You can use CCleaner to check for any software issue.

--> Look for any unwanted processes using task manager.

--> Check hardware for overheating.

If you find everything normal then I suggest you to format your system.